# Superposition of a subset of integers

Tags: programming, qiskit

I am trying to do the superposition of a subset of integers using qiskit. For instance: $|13\rangle + |14\rangle + ... |N\rangle$ (uniform superposition) without the part $|0\rangle + |1\rangle + ... + |12\rangle$. Is it possible? How can I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this :

```
n = 5 #number of qubits
N = 2**n #32
sup = [0.]*N
start = 12 #your 13, considering list index starts at 0
norm = N-start #used for normalisation of the vector we'll pass
for i in range(start, N): 
    #creation of the list where the 0s are at indices on the first part you don't want
    sup[i]=np.sqrt(1/norm)

qc = QuantumCircuit(n)
qc.initialize(sup, range(n))
qc.draw()
```

Tell me if something isn't clear :)

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. for your answer. It's really good